# Creating dynamic class attributes (not instance ones)

Tags: python, oop, attributes

Is there any way of dynamically create class attributes ?

```py
class MyClass:

   attr_one = 'Same_string_with_just_different_value_one'
   attr_two = 'Same_string_with_just_different_value_two'
   attr_three = 'Same_string_with_just_different_value_three'
   [...]
```

I tried overloading `__new__` like this:

```py
class MyClass:

   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      map_attr_to_value = {
         'one': 'value_one',
         'two': 'value_two',
         'three': 'value_three',
         [...]
      }
      for attr, value in map_attr_to_value.items():
         setattr(cls, f"attr_{attr}", f"Same_string_with_just_different_{value}")
         return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

But that don't work for me, since MyClass is never instantiated, `__new__` is never called. I don't even know if it's actually possible.

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: I'm a bit dumb, by the question do you mean instantly create attributes when the class is created?

Comment: Actually, there was a missing information, for each attributes, the value is the same with just one part different. So i was looking if it was possible to refactore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the class dynamically using [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Arguments are `classname, superclasses, attributedict`:

```
map_attr_to_value = {
    'one': 'value_one',
    'two': 'value_two',
    'three': 'value_three',
}

A = type(
    "A", (),
    {f"attr_{attr}": value
     for attr, value in map_attr_to_value.items()}
)
print(A)
print(A.attr_one)
```

Out:

```
<class '__main__.A'>
value_one
```

Comment: That's nice! Not sure if i'm gonna use it some day, but that's the kind of trick i was looking for, just by curiosity.